# Cat with kidney disease

Tags: cats, health, diseases, senior-pet, urinary-tract-disease

My cat Jack, aged 11, had skin condition about April 1st. Mange was diagnosed and treated over three week period. It seemed fine and then he fell ill again. Vet thought it was respiratory infection but mentioned it could be kidney issue. He gave him antibiotics and steroids, and Jack quickly recovered. It was great for a week and then the cat fell ill again. He was lethargic and his eyesight seemed to worsen as he was bumping into things. Blood tests were done yesterday and showed advanced kidney and pancreatic disease. Vet is coming tomorrow with treatment plan.

What should I expect? All info and experience of this appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately my beloved Jack was put to sleep as he was suffering. Thanks to all who advised and tried to help. Sorely missed.

Comment: I am sorry for your loss. Thanks for posting this update for us.

Comment: My condolences.

Answer (score 2):

**Kidney diseases are not a death sentence.**

I have looked after a Maine Coon with Kidney disease for three years and we lost him because of diabetes rather than renal failure.

- Replace regular cat food with renal food. Renal food is more expensive than the regular food, yet it stops or slows kidney deterioration.
- Make your cat drink more water. It is hard to tell the cats to drink more water [so you might need to trick him](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23297/should-i-add-water-to-wet-food-to-provide-extra-hydration). I personally water down the wet food. My current cat doesn't show any signs of dislike towards this water downed formula.
- Administer the drugs the vet will give you. These will help a fast recovery but you still have to make life style changes I mentioned above to be effective.
- If the kidney function is too low, have your cat get into dialysis for a few times.

Answer (score -1):

I'm so sorry your pet is doing poorly.  I'm hesitant to give any specific advice because I'm not a vet, but I think you should mentally prepare yourself for the possibility your vet recommends euthanasia.

Unfortunately, kidneys don't really recover very well after being damaged, and kidney disease is a very common cause of death in cats.  If the kidneys are badly damaged, there's just nothing that can be done.  According to cat health articles such as [this one](http://Cats%20with%20kidney%20disease%20may%20also%20develop%20high%20blood%20pressure.%20This%20may%20cause%20blindness,%20behavioural%20changes%20or%20neurological%20signs.) posted on catdoctor.com, which I quote:

> Cats with kidney disease may also develop high blood pressure. 
>    This may cause blindness, behavioural changes or neurological signs.

Your cat's apparent blindness may be a sign that your cat's kidneys are doing poorly.  From personal experience, I had a cat with chronic kidney disease that suddenly became unable to walk.  It was almost certainly due to the kidney disease catching up with her, and the vet recommended she be euthanized.

However, on a more positive note, it may be the case that your cat's kidneys are still well enough that the disease can be slowed and managed, through diet, or possibly other things your vet recommends.  Also from personal experience, my cat, before she had become that poorly, had the disease for many years, which we managed by giving her prescription cat food designed to manage kidney disease.

Comment: Thank you. Vet has given medication and diet food to try but not holding out much hope. Says we will know if effective in a week. Today he’s quite active but think it’s lots of steroids.  Yes I am dreading the fact that he may need to be euthanised but will do what’s best for him. Thank you again for taking the time.

Comment: Note that all cats eventually suffer from kidney disease if something else doesn't get them first.

Comment: I am sorry but it is a long stretch from advanced kidney disease to death. With proper care, he would be able to survive for some time.